# Is there a way to make Riverpod's StreamProvider go into loading state only on the initial call?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

This is something I've wondered about for a while. It is hindering the UX to show a loading Icon whenever the stream changes when using `{StreamProvider's name}.when` method.

I can already make it work by using a `StreamBuilder` instead and using the `StreamProvider`'s `.stream` property as the stream. This way, it only shows a loading icon when no data is present, and if new data arrives on top of old data, it shows the old data until the new data is "loaded".
But I find that as a workaround and was wondering if there is a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version 2.0.0 updates how AsyncValue is dealt with, making what you're asking the new default behaviour.

You can try it out now using version `flutter_riverpod: ^2.0.0-dev.0`